# SSH - Logging in with only one command?

Tags: gnome, ssh, raspberrypi

I got a Raspberry Pi 3 which I got fully running, its running Debian with XFCE desktop. I knew it was possible to use X11 forwarding.

Now, my question, is it possible to start a program with one command? I want to create a desktop entry for my main OS (Ubuntu GNOME) so I can just click it and it will run.

I have to create a .sh file for this..

Is there a way to login and start a program with only ONE command? Let´s say I want to start GIMP.

Usually I do this:

```
ssh -XC -C -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc username@IP
```

Then it will open the SSH client for the RPi and ask for a password, then I type this in, and lastly I have to type in ¨Gimp¨ so it starts on my main desktop.

Is there a way I can do all of this with only ONE command? I want to make a desktop entry, but I dont want the terminal everytime to open up and ask for my password to login to the Pi.

Answer (score 7):

> Usually I do this:
>
> ```
> ssh -XC -C -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc username@IP
> ```

Don't do that. Use `-Y` to make sure it will be working in future. Selection of "bad ciphers" does not help these days, nor the `-C` for compression.

```
ssh -Y username@IP
```

is just enough.

If you don't want to write all of them, there is `ssh_config`, where you can store entry like this:

```
Host pi
  Hostname <IP>
  User username
  ForwardX11 yes
```

and then you can connect simply by typing `ssh pi`.

To get rid of the password, prompt, it is good choice to set up public key authentication (in short):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id pi
```

Lastly, you can start the programs on the `pi` directly from `ssh`, such as

```
ssh pi gimp
```

which can be simply used as an shortcut for desktop, if you wish. But I think it is faster to type that, than search some icons on the desktop :)

Comment: Is it possible to share the whole XFCE taskbar onto my desktop?

Comment: Not using X11 forwarding in SSH.

Comment: You could use ECDSA instead of RSA for the Pi.  I recommend `-t rsa -b 4096` for RSA keys (external), but for the Pi's I recommend `-t ecdsa -b 521`.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into learning about and putting `UsePubKeyAuthentication yes` and `IdentityFile /path/to/private.key` in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Why are you suggesting `-Y` instead of `-X`?

Comment: @OrangeDog with today defaults, it does not matter, because `ForwardX11Trusted` is `on` by default, but if it would not be, it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full desktop from the Pi you can install xnest, and use that.  Xnest is a X client that is also a X server, so it gives you a second X server running as a sub-window in your current desktop.

I've set up a passwordless key to ssh to a vm with, and I've created a .ssh/config file with a shortcut as described by Jakuje so what I do is

```
user@host:~/ $ Xnest :1 &
user@host:~/ $ DISPLAY=:1 ssh myvm mate-session
```

This starts a Xnest "server" on my machine located at :1 (your regular display is :0), and sends that process to the background.  Then I set my DISPLAY variable for that shell to point to the Xnest display, and ssh in to my vm using the info from my .ssh/config and starts a full MATE desktop session.   Replace the mate-session with whatever command starts a desktop session on your remote machine.

Comment: I get this: XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)

Comment: What I also noticed, is that both monitors are Screen 0. Any way to make the second monitor Screen 1?

Comment: @OctaVIve - that would require changing your xorg.conf (or whatever X server you are using) and may "separate" your dual monitor setup into 2 separate monitors... Your error could be because of how X is being started, each distro is a tad different. Open a terminal and do "set | grep DISPLAY" - it will tell you your default.  Add 1 to whatever number is given.